# How to enumerate keys from list and get values without hardcoding keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How to enumerate keys from list and get values without hard coding keys? `my_list` contains tuples and I am trying to generate dictionary based on the position of the tuple in list. `num` in `enumerate` gives number like 0, 1,2, ...etc.

```
my_list = [(1,2),(2,3),(4,5),(8,12)]
my_list

di = {'0':[],'1':[]} #manually - how to automate with out specifying keys from enumarate function?
for num,i in enumerate(my_list):
    di['0'].append(i[0])
    di['1'].append(i[0])
print(di) # {'0': [1, 2, 4, 8], '1': [1, 2, 4, 8]}
```

Output - How do I get this result?

```
di = {'0':[(1,2)],
      '1':[(2,3)],
      '2':[(4,5)],
      '3':[(8,12)]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just enumerate your way through the list:

```py
my_list = [(1,2),(2,3),(4,5),(8,12)]

di = {str(index):[item] for (index,item) in enumerate(my_list)}
```

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you are looking for?

You can use `enumerate` to get the index of each tuple in the list and then create a `dict comprehension`.

```
di = {str(i):[t] for i,t in enumerate(my_list)}
di
```

```
{'0': [(1, 2)], 
 '1': [(2, 3)], 
 '2': [(4, 5)], 
 '3': [(8, 12)]}
```

Comment: The keys should be strings.

Comment: He has the keys as strings, so not quite, but the OP should be able to extrapolate from this to the answer.

Comment: thanks for catching that, updated. just a simple fix